# Split a paragraph into lines

Tags: python

I have this paragraph in a variable

```
 "Information about this scan : abc version : 5.2.5 pqr version : 201 403061815 hello kdshfldfs;dfkfjljcsdlc sljc lsjclsj csjclks cscjsld"
```

I  want to fetch 'abc version' and  'pqr version'.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: There's a built-in `str.splitlines` method.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly do you want to extract? The texts `"5.2.5"` and `"201 403061815"`? If so, by what rule are we supposed to find them (how are start, content and end of these texts defined)? Please be precise, otherwise you're not likely to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
string = "Your Paragraph String"
string = string.split()
abc_version = string[string.index('abc')+3]
```

AND

```
pqr_version = string[string.index('pqr')+3] #This will give 201
```

OR

```
pqr_version = ' '.join(string[string.index('pqr')+3:string.index('pqr')+5]) #This will give 201 403061815
```

Please specify where your `pqr` version string starts and ends.